# iOS - Start Monitoring Significant Location Change when app is terminated - Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, locationmanager

has anyone here ever had location services working, even with the app is not running - using Significant Location Change? Basically, I have the app running, gather location data (confirmed) then closed the app entirely. set up code below.

```
class LocationService: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    public static let shared = LocationService()
    var delegate: LocationServiceDelegate?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!
    private var startTime: Date?
    private let apiService = APIService()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        self.setUpLocationServices()
    }

private func setUpLocationServices() {
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    //self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
}



 // in app delegate

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        print("starting launching options")

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

       self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
```

it is my understanding that both the standard and significant services can run in tandem (the docs say that the significant monitoring will ignore the desiredAccuracy and Filters). However, I did try using a few location manager delegate methods from the main AppDelegate to stop and start the standard and significant services separately and it still doesn't seem to work.

I have all the Usage Descriptions Required and have Location Updates checked under Capabilities for background modes. I also make sure that when getting the privacy prompt I select "Always Allow".

I went driving around last night for 10 mins and well over 500m and the app did not relaunch in the background. Also I tried it under the simulator(iOS 12.2) using Freeway mode(on 208) and still didnt work, even after 30 mins I didnt get a new location event to spawn. Any clue to how to get this to work or anything else I am missing?

I know there are a few past posts regarding this but most of them are old. Didn't know if there was something going on since iOS 8/9 that has changed?

Comment: Pretty sure the significant location change works based on your pre-defined (or user-defined) places (areas where the detection work). If you need to detect "visits" (places where the user stops walking for some time), maybe you want to check out for [CLVisit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clvisit). Note that the APIs in general need to have a `CLLocationManager` instantiated in the App Delegate to work. By defining a property in the `AppDelegate` class is enough: `private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()`.

Comment: you can do Region Based (geofencing) but thats not what I am doing here. the other option is to start monitoring significant location changes (as the code does above). I am not tracking people walking to certain places. this will be used with people riding/driving.

Comment: Anyway, it should work like the visits API: you need an instance of `CLLocationManager` in your AppDelegate. Try adding `let locationManager = CLLocationManager()` and `locationManager.delegate = self` to your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, it should do the trick for your app to be relaunched.

Comment: Can you show your `didFinishLaunching` code?  You need to specifically detect that your app is being launched by a location event and re-establish location services. You don't simply receive location delegate callbacks. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background?language=objc

Comment: right now I was relying on the fact that when didFinishLaunching occurs, the viewDidLoad method executes on my VC(automatically) and that uses a static shared Location class(public static let shared = LocationService()). I can confirm that this does happen via breakpoints. in this override init of the Location class we call the private method that the original code shows. 

it is working now, it seems but only when i initially start both types of services. can i not start the location services this way or do i have to create that right in the App Delegate (which seems wrong)?

Comment: ideally I want to start standard location services when you first open the app and continue to use that when the user has the app in background mode (not terminated). in both cases I want to update the location every 5 seconds. When the app is terminated I want to use the significant service to launch the app again and continue to only update the location ~500m instead of using the standard service - unless the user physically opens the app again. trying to figure out how to logically make all that work, when setting up the location services - where ever that takes place (code updated above)

Comment: No, that approach won't work. Once your application is in the background it is too late to start significant updates. Also there is no guarantee that `willTerminate` will be called. There should be no issue with running standard updates and significant location change updates at the same time.

Comment: ok thanks. i think i got it now